# How to save a value in a variable within a for loop without overwriting in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This is my attempted code:

```
for i = 1:length(X) %X is a CSV matrix 50x4
    Y = X(i, :) % fetching each row of X
    dist = pdist2(Y, X2, 'euclidean') %X2 is another matrix 100x4
    sumOfdist = sum(dist);
end;
meanResult = mean(sum)
```

sumOfdist will always be overwritten on each iteration and thus my meanResult stores the mean of only the last iteration. What would be the best way to store the sum of all the values through each iteration and using it outside the forloop to calculate the mean - without using global variables?

Comment: First you should rename your variable "sum" to something else; And you can write sum1 = sum1 + sum(dist)

Comment: Right, it isn't sum either way - just called it that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using loop, and intead just do:

```
X=randn(6, 4);
X2=randn(10,4);
D = pdist2(X,X2,'euclidean');
sums=sum(D);
res=mean(sums)
```

In the code above, the i-th row in `D` consists of list of distances of `X(i,:)` from every row in `X2`. Then in `sums` we store the sum of each row in `D`.

Comment: Will that store the sum of all the Euclidean distances of each row of X from every row in X2 in D?

Comment: Yes, this will be stored in sums. For example, the first element in sums is the sum of all the distances from the first row in X to each one of the rows in X2